# Blender: Rendering images and producing an animation

Tags: python, animation, render, blender, keyframe

I am new to Blender and I’m having a bit of a tough time understanding its key concepts. I am using Blender 2.82 and working with Python scripting. My project consists of using Python to do the following:

1. Move object slightly.
2. Take picture with camera 1, camera 2, camera 3, and camera 4.
3. Repeat.

I had a script that did that. However, I wanted to save the position of my object (a sphere) every time I changed it during the loop in an animation, so I could later see what I did. When trying to insert keyframes for animation in my loop, it seems as if my sphere didn’t move. Below is my code. When I remove the lines that include `frame_set` and `keyframe_insert`, my sphere moves as I can see from my rendered images. I think I am confusing some kind of concept… Any help would be appreciated. The goal of this is to produce the images I would obtain from four cameras placed around an object, that is moving, so as to simulate a mocap system.
Why does inserting a keyframe change all of the images being rendered?

```
import bpy, bgl, blf,sys
import numpy as np
from bpy import data, ops, props, types, context

cameraNames=''

# Loop all command line arguments and try to find "cameras=east" or similar
for arg in sys.argv:
    words=arg.split('=')
    if ( words[0] == 'cameras'):
     cameraNames = words[1]

sceneKey = bpy.data.scenes.keys()[0]

# Loop all objects and try to find Cameras
bpy.data.scenes[sceneKey].render.image_settings.file_format = 'JPEG'
bpy.data.scenes[sceneKey].cycles.max_bounces=12
bpy.data.scenes[sceneKey].render.tile_x=8
bpy.data.scenes[sceneKey].render.tile_y=8
bpy.data.scenes[sceneKey].cycles.samples = 16
bpy.data.scenes[sceneKey].cycles.caustics_reflective = False
bpy.data.scenes[sceneKey].cycles.caustics_refractive = False

bpy.data.objects['Sphere'].location=[1,1,1] 
frame_num=0
for i in range(0,2): #nframes
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame_num)
    for obj in bpy.data.objects:
        # Find cameras that match cameraNames
        if ( obj.type =='CAMERA') and ( cameraNames == '' or obj.name.find(cameraNames) != -1) :

          # Set Scenes camera and output filename
            bpy.data.scenes[sceneKey].camera = obj
            bpy.data.scenes[sceneKey].render.filepath = '//'+obj.name+"_"+str(i) 

          # Render Scene and store the scene
            bpy.ops.render.render( write_still=True )

    bpy.data.objects['Sphere'].keyframe_insert(data_path="location",index=-1)
    frame_num+=1
    bpy.data.objects['Sphere'].location=[2,2,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge of python, but you can try to do key frame animation manually and make a script which will render the pictures after a set of key frames(whenever the object has moved to a new location)

It is not too hard (I'm talking about only the animation), just press the circle button near the play animation button on the timeline. This will turn on auto key framing and you just have to go to the desired key frame and move the object according to your need.